# Unknown function registry: 'scorers' with spacy webservice with flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

i'm using spacy in conjunction with flask and anaconda to create a simple webservice. Everything worked fine, until today when i tried to run my code. I got this error and i don't understand what the problem really is. I think this problem has more to do with spacy than flask.

Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/en/<textstr>')
def eng(textstr):    
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
    doc = nlp(textstr)
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text,list(token.morph), token.pos_,token.dep_)
        if token.pos_ == "VERB":
            print("This is a Verb: "+token.text_)
    return "Success"
```

When i enter http://127.0.0.1:5000/en/Hello%20my%20name%20is%20Stackoverflow i get this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\User\flask_api_env\main.py", line 85, in eng
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 50, in load
return util.load_model(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 324, in load_model
return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 357, in load_model_from_package
return cls.load(vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_trf\__init__.py", line 10, in load
return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 517, in load_model_from_init_py
return load_model_from_path(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 392, in load_model_from_path
nlp = load_model_from_config(config, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 429, in load_model_from_config
nlp = lang_cls.from_config(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 1672, in from_config
nlp.add_pipe(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 774, in add_pipe
pipe_component = self.create_pipe(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 660, in create_pipe
resolved = registry.resolve(cfg, validate=validate)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py", line 729, in resolve
resolved, _ = cls._make(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py", line 778, in _make
filled, _, resolved = cls._fill(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py", line 833, in _fill
filled[key], validation[v_key], final[key] = cls._fill(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py", line 832, in _fill
promise_schema = cls.make_promise_schema(value, resolve=resolve)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py", line 1023, in make_promise_schema
func = cls.get(reg_name, func_name)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\flask_api_env\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 127, in get
raise RegistryError(Errors.E892.format(name=registry_name, available=names))


catalogue.RegistryError: [E892] Unknown function registry: 'scorers'.

Available names: annotation_setters, architectures, augmenters, batchers, callbacks, cli, datasets, displacy_colors, factories, initializers, languages, layers, lemmatizers, loggers, lookups, losses, misc, models, ops, optimizers, readers, schedules, span_getters, tokenizers
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: The `scorers` registry was added at some point after the release of v3.0, you should be able to fix this by upgrading spaCy.

Comment: Thank you @polm23 , you are always reliable!!! Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is an internal error from `spaCy`. You use the `en_core_web_trf` model provided by `spaCy`. It's not even a third-party model. It seems to be completely internal to `spaCy`.

You could try upgrading `spaCy` to the latest version.

The registry name `scorers` appears to be valid (at least as of `spaCy` v3.0). See this table: https://spacy.io/api/top-level#section-registry

The page describing the model you use: https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_trf

The `spacy.load()` function documentation: https://spacy.io/api/top-level#spacy.load